# Birt 4.8.0: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine error

Tags: java, birt

I keep getting the following error trying to start Birt RCP Report Designer 4.8.0-20180626

[image: Birt error]

Birt RCP Report Designer 4.9.0-20220315 works without any problems. What could be the problem? I downloaded both from [the official site](https://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/drops/)

I have JDK 17 running.

Comment: Don't know if it can help. I had a similar problem with Eclipse (I think the error was the same too). In my case it was a JDK problem. I had installed only JDK18. When I also installed JDK16 for other purposes, Eclipse magically started working again. Perhaps you're having the same issue.

Comment: Hmm, OK, but I thought Java is always backwards compatible?

Comment: Don't ask me. I only know that that is how it worked for me. I also had troubles with Gradle, that supports  JDK17 but is not JDK18 (that's why I had to install the previous JDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIRT 4.8 needs a Java version between Java 6 and Java 8.
I'm not absolutely sure, but AFAIK it even needs an *Oracle* JRE.

BIRT 4.9 needs Java version >= 11.

And no, Java definitely isn't always backwards compatible.
Only most of it, most of the time :-)